# Reflect manipulations on one list in a second list

Tags: list-manipulation

I'd like to mirror the manipulations (specifically deletion, insertion, and reassignment) done at each position of two equally-sized lists, based on the contents of only one of those lists. As an example say I have

```
l1 = {a, b, c, 4, e, f, 7, 8, i}
l2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

and then I want to remove all the numbers from the `l1`, then also remove elements at the same positions in `l2` yielding

```
l1`={a,b,c,e,f,i}
l2`={1,2,3,5,6,9}
```

I can achieve this specific behavior by creating a selector list according to the conditions imposed on the first list and then applying `Pick` to both, like

```
sel[x_List] := Table[! MatchQ[ic, _?NumberQ], {ic, x}]

Pick[l1,sel[l1]]
Pick[l2,sel[l1]]
```

The above yields the correct `` l1` `` and `` l2` ``. The function `sel` can also be used in a more cumbersome fashion with `Insert` and `Part` for insertion and reassignment, but all of this seems janky and my heart insists there is a more elegant way. Is this the best that can be done?

I should also note that it cannot be assumed that elements being removed from both lists are equal, nor are the lists canonically ordered. The only safe assumptions are that the lists are equally sized, and that the operation performed at position `n` in `l1` should be repeated at position `n` in `l2` (but determined only by the value at position `n` in `l1`).

Comment: The obvious (and perhaps uncomfortable) solution is working with `l = Transpose[{l1,l2}]` ....

Comment: When using `Pick` this might be more straight forward: `Pick[l2, NumericQ /@ l1, False]`

Comment: ...and there's always `Position[]` to fall back on.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe start with a basic test:

```
test=NumericQ /@ l1
```

This can be used with `Pick`

```
Pick[l2, test, False]
```

If you want positions you could always use `Position` directly

```
pos=Position[l1, _?NumericQ]
Delete[l1, pos]
```

or use `Pick` again to get positions and test for `True` or `False` depending on what you want to do:

```
Pick[Range[Length[l1]],test,True|False]
```

and/or

```
List /@ Pick[Range[Length[l1]],test,True|False]
```

...depending on what format you require

Comment: With `Position[]`, I imagined something like `pos = Position[l1, x_ /; ! NumericQ[x], 1, Heads -> False]; Extract[#, pos] & /@ {l1, l2}`.

Comment: @J.M. My answer was a bit terse but with `Position` I was thinking more in terms of using with `Delete`

Comment: Oh, of course; with `Delete[]` you don't need to negate the expression test. :)

Comment: I'm down voting because this answer seems to make an incorrect assumption about the generation of the dependent list. Also, it doesn't seem any simpler for the specific manipulation it address than the one presented in the question, but that's a matter of opinion.

Comment: @IPoiler I based my answer on finding the positions because that was where the OP needed some work. What you do with the positions once found is straight forward using `Delete`, `Insert` and `Part`

Answer (score 0):

In the vein of @belisariushassettled's comment, the lists can be joined as an array to have the rows operated on after `Transpose`.

```
l1 = {a, b, c, 4, e, f, 7, 8, i}
l2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
l=Transpose[{l1,l2}]
```

### Deletion

Example: Remove based on positions of `l1` which contain integers:

```
ld=Transpose@DeleteCases[l, {_Integer, _}];
l1`=ld[[1]]
l2`=ld[[2]]
```

> ```
> {a,b,c,e,f,i}
> {1,2,3,5,6,9}
> ```

### Insertion

Example: Insert elements after positions in `l1` which contain integers:

```
li=Transpose@Insert[l, {y, z}, Position[l, {_Integer, _}] + 1];
l1`=li[[1]]
l2`=li[[2]]
```

> ```
> {a,b,c,4,y,e,f,7,y,8,y,i}
> {1,2,3,4,z,5,6,7,z,8,z,i}
> ```

### Reassignment

Example: Transform elements to letters at positions where `l1` contains integers:

```
lr=Transpose@ReplaceAll[l, {x_Integer, y_} :> {FromLetterNumber[x],FromLetterNumber[x + 1]}];
l1`=lr[[1]]
l2`=lr[[2]]
```

> ```
> {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i}
> {1,2,3,e,5,6,h,i,9}
> ```